# Effect of stored procedures on network traffic in Access/SQL setup

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, traffic

I am currently administering/developing an Access 2010 frontend/SQL backend database. We are trying to improve frontend performance, and one solution that has been suggested is pushing a lot of the VBA that is running the front end down into stored procedures on the server. I'm fairly proficient in VBA, but very new to SQL and network architecture. Everything I've turned up on google has been information about splitting the database, which is already done, rather than information about network loads resulting from running stored procedures vs running VBA.

**What is the difference in network traffic between the current setup and pushing this action down to a stored procedure?**

As a specific example, if I'm populating a form in the current setup, there are a few queries run to provide data to different elements on the form. With the current architecture, does Access retrieve the queried tables from the backend, query them client-side and then populate the data? How would that be different in terms of network traffic from, say, executing a SP when the form loads, and only transferring the data necessary for displaying the form?

The end goal is to reduce the chattiness between Access and SQL, and I'm mostly trying to figure out exactly what is happening where.

Comment: The extent to which network traffic would be affected depends on a lot of factors and there's no real way to know whether such a change would be worthwhile without some real-world testing with a few of your applications. You probably should get to know a bit about [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), set up some realistic test cases, and see what kind of results you get for your particular situation.

Comment: In your example where "there are a few queries run to provide data to different elements on the form", if you write a stored procedure that does all of that in one shot you'll probably cut down on traffic. Network load is partly about chattiness, but it's also about the size of the result set traveling across the wire, so if you take a one-shot front end query that returns 1MB of result data and change it to a stored procedure call that returns 1MB of result data you won't reduce the load.

Comment: MS Access depends a lot on indexes, a query that works with useful indexes will be a lot faster. Access will only pull the indexed data.

Comment: maybe it is worth mentioning, standalone SQL servers are much faster than native ACCESS JET/ACE engine. I'm not sure about network load but you will feel the increased speed when you use stored procedures. to compare this, run the same query via "pass_through" query and see/feel the difference.

Comment: Thanks--I'll set up some tests and see if I can nail down the critical factors, though I doubt very much that the actual data load is the problem (the DB isn't big enough).

Comment: This link has lots of useful info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204.aspx   Start reading from the title "Moving Query Processing to the Server"  (bear in mind this article is 9 years old, but it might still be worth reading)

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, if you launch a form open with a where clause to restrict the form to one record, then using a bound form, or adopting a stored procedure will NOT result in any difference or reduction in network traffic.

Any local access query based on a table simply will request the one record. There is no “local” concept of processing in this regards EVEN with a linked table. Note the word “table” or singular here.

Access does not and will not pull down a whole table unless you have such forms and quires without any “where” clause to restrict the data pulled.

In other words if you have a poorly designed form, dump and change that design to something in which you now ONLY pull down the one record, then of course the setup will result in reduced network traffic.

However the above reduction is NOT DUE to adopting the stored procedure but ONLY that of adopting a design in which you restrict the records requested into the form.

So doing something poorly and then improving that process is NOT a justification to adopt stored procedures.

Thus in the case of pulling records into a form the using a stored procedure will NOT improve performance. Worse is binding a form to a stored procedure results in a form that is READY ONLY anyway!

So stored procedures don’t necessary increase performance or reduce network traffic when talking about loading a record into a form in terms of response time or performance.

If you have to do large amounts of recordset processing then of course adopting a stored procedure can save network performance. So in place of some VBA code to process 100,000 payroll reocrds, then yes moving such code server side will help. However processing a 100,000 payroll records is NOT common task and is NOT a user interface issue in most cases anyway. In other words, you don’t have a slow loading form or slow response time to load such forms. In other words, such types of processing are NOT done interactive by users waiting for a form to load.

SQL server is indeed a high performance system, and also a system that can scale to many users.

If you write your application in c++, or VB or in your case with ms-access, in GENERAL the performance of all of these tools will BE THE SAME.

In other words...sql server is rather nice, and is a standard system used in the IT industry.

However, sql server will NOT solve your performance issues without efforts on your part. And, it turns out that MOST of those same efforts also make your non sql server Access applications run better.

In fact, we see many posts that mention moving the back end data
to sql server actually slowed things down. (and in fact on a single machine, Access JET (now called ACE) is actually FASTER THEN SQL server (so when single user on same machine – Access is faster than SQL server on the same machine in most cases).

A few things:

Having a table with 75k records is quite small. Let’s assume you have 12 users. With a just a 100% file base system (jet), and no sql server, then the performance of that system should really have screamed.

I have some applications out there with 50, or 60 HIGHLY related tables. With 5 to 10 users on a network, response time is instant. I don't think any form load takes more than one second. Many of those 60+ tables are highly relational and in the 50 to 75k records range.

So, with my 5 users I see no reason why I can’t scale to 15 users with such small tables in the 75,000 record range. And this is without SQL server.

If the application did not perform with such small tables of only 75k records then upsizing to sql server will do absolute nothing to fix performance issues. In fact, in the sql server newsgroups you see weekly posts by people who find that upgrading to sql actually slowed things down.

I even seem some very cool numbers showing that some queries where actually MORE EFFICIENT in terms of network use by JET then sql server.

My point here is that technology will NOT solve performance problems. However, good designs that make careful use of limited bandwidth resources is the key here. So, if the application was not written with good performance in mind then you kind are stuck with a poor design!

I mean, when using a JET file share, you grab a invoice from the 75k record table only the one record is transferred down the network with a file share (and, sql server will also only transfer one record). So, at this point, you
really will NOT notice any performance difference by upgrading to SQL Server. There is no magic here. And adopting a SQL stored procedure will be even a GREATER waste of time!

And adopting a stored procedure in place of above will NOT gain you performance either!

Sql server is a robust and more scalable product then is JET. And, security, backup and host of other reasons make sql server a good choice. However, sql server will NOT solve a performance problem with dealing with such small tables as 75k records

Of course, when efforts are made to utilize sql server, then significant advances in performance can be realized.

I will give a few tips...these apply when using ms-access as a file share (without a server), or even odbc to sql server:

** Ask the user what they need before you load a form!

The above is so simple, but so often I see the above concept ignored. For example, when you walk up to an instant teller machine, does it download every account number and THEN ASK YOU what you want to do?

In access, it is downright silly to open up form attached to a table WITHOUT FIRST asking the user what they want! So, if it is a customer invoice, get the invoice number, and then load up the form with the ONE record. How can one record be slow? When done editing the record and the form is closed, and you are back to the prompt ready to do battle with the next customer.

You can read up on how this "flow" of a good user interface works here (and this applies to both JET, and sql server applications):

http://www.kallal.ca/Search/index.html

My only point here is restrict the form to only the ONE record the user needs. You don't need nor gain by using a stored procedure to accomplish this task. I am always dismayed how often a developer builds a nice form, attaches it to a large table, and then opens it and the throws this form attached to some huge table and then tells the users to go have at this and have fun. Don't we have any kind of concern for those poor users? Often, the user will not even know how to search for something!

So prompt, and asking the user also makes a HUGE leap forward in usability. And, the big bonus is reduced network traffic too! Gosh better and faster, and less network traffic! What more do we want!

** USE CAUTION with quires that require more than one linked table

JET has a real difficult time joining odbc tables together. Often the Access data engine (jet/Ace) does a good job, but often such joins are slow. However most forms for editing data are NOT based on a multi-table query. (so again, a stored procedure will not speed up form load for editing of data).

The simple solution for such multiple joins (for both forms and reports) is build the sql server side as a view, and then link to that view.

This view approach is MUCH less work then a stored procedure and results in the joins occurring server side. And results view are updatable as opposed to READ ONLY when you adopt stored procedures. And performance of such views will again equal that of stored procedure in THIS context.

So once gain, adopting stored procedures DOES NOT help and is more expensive from a developer cost then simply using a view. Really this just amounts to people suggesting that you rack up bills and use developer time to create something that yields nothing over that of a view except more billable hours.

I don't think it needs pointing out that if the query in question already runs well, then the above can be ignored, but just keep in mind that local queries with more than one table based on links to sql server can often run slow. So, just be aware of the above.

This view trick also applies well to combo boxes.

So one can continue to use bound forms to a linked table but one simply needs to restrict the form to the ONE RECORD you need.

You can safely open up to a single invoice form etc. but simply ENSURE you open such forms (openForm) by restricting records via the "where" clause. No view, or stored procedure is required here.

Bound forms are way less work then un-bound forms and performance is generally just as good anyway when done right.

Avoid large loading of combo boxes. A combo box is good for about 100 entries. After that you are torturing the user (what they got to look through 100s of entries). So, keep things like combo boxes down to a min size. This is both faster and MORE importantly it is kinder to your users.

After all, at the end of the day what we really want is to treat users well. It seems that treating the users well, and reducing the bandwidth (amount of data) goes hand in hand.

So, better applications treat the users well and run faster! (this is good news!)

So, #1 tip is to reduce the data that you transfer into a form.

Using stored procedures is not required in the vast majority of cases and will not reduce bandwidth requirements anymore then adopting where clauses and views.